# Fetch Stored procedure log from system tables in SQL - Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am looking to retrieve the SP execution log from system table.

I looking to retrieve the parameters passed for the sp at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There is no such thing available without running a trace or capturing system events.

There are NO logs that Sql Server maintains itself that will help you.

Your best course of action in the future would be to log this inside the procedure when it's call. Profile traces might help you, but depending on how the procedure was called, it also might not.

Not the answer you were looking for, but it's the answer none the less.